# how to use tokio::spawn with &self?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I'm made a multithreaded server using std::thread (1 thread / connection), but now I want to convert it to use tokio and async/await.I don't know how to get over this error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
  --> src/server/mod.rs:52:24
   |
50 |     pub async fn run(&self) {
   |                      -----
   |                      |
   |                      `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
   |                      let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
51 |         info!("server started");
52 |         let arc_self = Arc::new(self);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                        |
   |                        `self` escapes the associated function body here
   |                        argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

From this code:

```
pub async fn run(&self) {
        info!("server started");
        let arc_self = Arc::new(self);

        let listener_address = arc_self.settings.address.clone();
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(&listener_address)
            .await
            .expect("Failed to bind to the server address");

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            arc_self.listen(listener).await;
        });

        let arc_self_clone = arc_self.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            arc_self_clone.clean_cache().await;
        });
    }
```

I understand *why* this happens but I don't know how to get around it.

This was my first attempt, which worked only partially (clean_cache won't run, so it's not a valid solution):

```
pub async fn run(&self) {
        info!("server started");

        let listener_address = self.settings.address.clone();
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(&listener_address)
            .await
            .expect("Failed to bind to the server address");

        self.listen(listener).await; // blocks forever
        
        self.clean_cache().await; // will never get run
    }
```

This is what I came up with after browsing stack overflow: 
This code does not work, anything after async move is not run so neither listener nor clean_cache are not beign run.

```
pub async fn run(self: Arc<Self>) {
        info!("server started");
        let listener_address = self.clone().settings.address.clone();

        tokio::spawn({
            let me = Arc::clone(&self);
            eprintln!("yes");
            async move  {
                eprintln!("no");
                let listener = TcpListener::bind(&listener_address).await.unwrap();
                me.listen(listener).await;
            }
        });

        tokio::spawn({
            let me = Arc::clone(&self);
            async move {
                me.clean_cache().await;
            }
        });
    }
```

I also followed [this](https://ryhl.io/blog/actors-with-tokio/) tutorial on how to set up an actor, where exactly this problem is given as an example.Still I could only get this to work for the listener method, the server object beign moved afterwards so I coudn't make it run the clean_cache method aswell.

Comment: Can you show the code that invokes `run()`? It's possible the application is terminating before the background tasks ever get a chance to run.

Comment: Note also that the second `spawn` doesn't need to clone the `Arc` since you own it. I would suggest having the second block simply take ownership of `self`, or change the argument to `self: &Arc<Self>`, otherwise you are creating an unnecessary third `Arc`.

Comment: I tested it, even with an infinite loop at the end of run() the behaviour is the same.

Comment: An infinite loop blocks an executor thread. If you want to wait indefinitely in tokio, try `std::future::pending().await`.

Comment: when I run into the same problem, creating a udp listener, I ended up not using self.  I had to move all the trait functions that the listener used into their own property-less struct and cloning all necessary depedencies

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it like this, basically moving the responsibility of those two operations on another struct, then the lifetime is specific and it does need to outlive static

the three dots in the impl means, whatever arguments you may need to pass.

```
pub async fn run(self) {
        info!("server started");
        let listener_address = self.clone().settings.address.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move  {
                let listener = TcpListener::bind(&listener_address).await.unwrap();
                TCPRead::listen(listener);
            });

        tokio::spawn(async move {
                TCPRead::clean_cache();
            });
    }


....
struct TCPRead;
impl TCPRead {
  fn listen(...){}
  fn clean_cache(...){}
}
```